# how to send email confirmation in nodejs and SendGrid?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sendgrid

I have a NodeJs and ReactJs project, where a user can **register** and after the user is registered they will get an email to confirm their account.

so now when I register the email is working well. but it works with an email that I set in like this.

```
function sendMail() {
  const msg = {
    to: "someoneemail@gmail.com", 
    from: "myemail@gmail.com", 
    subject: "a subject",
    text: "some text herer",
    html: "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>",
  };
  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Email sent");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

module.exports = { sendMail };
```

**I need to remove this** `to: "someoneemail@gmail.com"` a*

1. nd instead set the user email, the user who to register on this
   system
2. and instead of `text:` i have to send the **token**.

so here is the registration part:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, emailAddress, password } = req.body;
  const user = await Users.findOne({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [{ fullName: fullName }, { emailAddress: emailAddress }],
    },
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(400).send({
      error: `some message.`,
    });
  } else {
    bcrypt
      .hash(password, 10)
      .then((hash) => {
        return {
          fullName: fullName,
          emailAddress: emailAddress,
          password: hash,
          isVerified: false,
        };
      })
      .then((user) => {
        const token = TokenGenerator.generate();
        const creator = Verifications.belongsTo(Users, { as: "user" });
        return Verifications.create(
          {
            token,
            user: user,
          },
          {
            include: [creator],
          }
        );
      })
      .then((verification) => {
        console.log("verification", verification);
        sendMail();
      })
      .then(() => res.json("User, Successmessage "));
  }
});
```

but the codes are not in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the parameters you need to the `sendMail` function:

```js
function sendMail(user, token) {
  const msg = {
    to: user.emailAddress, 
    from: "myemail@gmail.com", 
    subject: "Sending with SendGrid is Fun",
    text: token,
    html: `<strong>${token}</strong>`,
  };
  sgMail
    .send(msg)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Email sent");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Also inject the needed parameters in the promises:

```
 .then(async (user) => {
        const token = TokenGenerator.generate();
        const creator = Verifications.belongsTo(Users, { as: "user" });
        await Verifications.create(
          {
            token,
            user: user,
          },
          {
            include: [creator],
          }
        );
        return {user, token};
      })
      .then(({user, token}) => {
        sendMail(user, token);
      })
      .then(() => res.json("User, Successmessage "));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, for answering, it made the work, but I am not able to send the token to the user, just sent an empty email with the subject.

Comment: Maybe the token is not defined with TokenGenerator.generate(). You need also to include it in the html version

Comment: what do you mean by including in the HTML version? the TokenGenerator.generate() generating taken in the console.log, but it's not sending to the user with email.

Comment: Check the edit     html: `<strong>${token}</strong>`,

Comment: Yeah, yeah I already fixed this part thanks a lot!